# OpenLayers loop layers function

Tags: loops, openlayers, tile

In OpenLayers, I have a button (show), when I press on it, I got a layer on the map

My question:  How can I show many layers consequently With a certain frame rate
(Something like a loop!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to show a new/other layer every X seconds, use `setInterval`

let's assume that you somehow got an array of dates for which you have tiles, and a function `displayLayerByDate(dateObject)` that can show the layer.

```
function animatedLayers(arrayOfDates) {
  let currentIdx = 0;
  const handle = setInterval(function() {
    const currentDate = arrayOfDates[currentIdx];
    displayLayerByDate(dateObject);
  }, 5000); 
}
```